# window.postMessage doesn't work in Mac

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im try postMessage with window, and frame inside.

Here is code:

Window

```
function customHandler(callback){
    if (window.addEventListener) {  // all browsers except IE before version 9
        window.addEventListener ("message", callback, false);
    } else {
        if (window.attachEvent) {   // IE before version 9
            window.attachEvent("onmessage", callback);
        }
    }
}

customHandler(function(e) {
    console.log('WINDOW1: recv: ', e.data);

    if (e.data.status == true) {
        var data = {status: false, message: 'test'};
        console.log('WINDOW1: send: ', data);
        document.getElementById('regpopFrame').contentWindow.postMessage(data, "*");
    }
});


$(window).on('message', function(e) {
    console.log('WINDOW2: recv: ', e.originalEvent.data);

    if (e.originalEvent.data.status == true) {
        var data = {status: false, message: 'test'};
        console.log('WINDOW2: send: ', data);
        document.getElementById('regpopFrame').contentWindow.postMessage(data, "*");
    }
});

    window.onmessage = function(e) {
        console.log('WINDOW3: recv: ', e.data);

        if (e.data.status == true) {
            var data = {status: false, message: 'test'};
            console.log('WINDOW3: send: ', data);
            document.getElementById('regpopFrame').contentWindow.postMessage(data, "*");
        }
    };
```

iFrame

```
function customHandler(callback){
    if (window.addEventListener) {  // all browsers except IE before version 9
        window.addEventListener ("message", callback, false);
    } else {
        if (window.attachEvent) {   // IE before version 9
            window.attachEvent("onmessage", callback);
        }
    }
}

customHandler(function(e) {
    console.log('FRAME1: recv: ', e.data);

    if (e.data.status == true) {

        var data = {status: true, message: 'test'};
        console.log('FRAME1: send: ', data);
        parent.postMessage(data, "*");
    }
});


$(window).on('message', function(e) {
    console.log('FRAME2: recv: ', e.originalEvent.data);

    if (e.originalEvent.data.status == true) {
        var data = {status: true, message: 'test'};
        console.log('FRAME2: send: ', data);
        parent.postMessage(data, "*");
    }
});

window.onmessage = function(e) {
    console.log('FRAME3: recv: ', e.data);

    if (e.data.status == true) {
        var data = {status: true, message: 'test'};
        console.log('FRAME3: send: ', data);
        parent.postMessage(data, "*");
    }
};


$(window).load(function(){
   parent.postMessage({status: true, message: 'test'}, '*');
});
```

This code, work fine in my browser(Windows 10, Chrome)
But in client browser(Mac, Safari or Chrome) or (Windows 10, Chrome) not.

Also i've tryed postMessage with origins, this is not help too. 
What the problem here?

Comment: Have you solved the issue?